# Put multiple node and format them in another node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a type of node named "document". Each one have a document and I've put a taxonomy to have the language of the document.

Now I want to create a view (page) that show me all the documents in different languages.

Example of the output that I want to make :

Important-document.doc [download in English] [download in french] [download in swedish]

How can I make ? doing a new type of node named "document container" or allow multiple upload in the "document" node type ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a taxonomy term showing the language, I would add different fields to the document content type which consist of an upload of the document. That way each document node would have multiple documents attached to it with each attachment being a different language.

Using views output each node as a row and add the download links as the fields.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Sometimes I have 2 translations, sometimes 15, you think it's really the best way?

So you think I must implement 15 file uploads, and those file uploads are named 'document french', 'document english', and so on ?

Comment: I guess there's a few different ways really... In terms of usability, have you figured out how the row may look when the file has 15 different translations? But yes, you could do that, and then make them optional fields and hide if empty in the view.